# way to enable/disable log printing in Gtest runs over command line

Tags: logging, command-line, googletest

Need some way or to pass some argument over command line to enable and disable logging in Google Gtest framework so that i can enable or disable logging while running test and don't have to make changes inside the file..

Checked Gtest documentation and other tutorial but could not get any related help.

Comment: `./test >/dev/null`? What you have requested can be solved in the shell.